# Determinant of block matrix with commuting blocks + ring homomorphism

Tags: matrices, ring-theory, determinant

Let $A, B$ be commutative rings with unity and let $p$ be a positive integer. Suppose $\varphi:A\to M_p(B)$ is a ring homomorphism. Is it true that for any positive integer $q$ and any $M\in M_q(A)$
$$\det(\varphi(M)) = \det(\varphi(\det(M)))~?$$
where the leftmost $\det$ is the determinant on $M_{pq}(B)$, the middle one that on $M_{q}(B)$ and the rightmost one that on $M_{p}(A)$? (And we denote $\varphi$ the natural extension of $\varphi$ to a ring homomorphism $M_q(A)\to M_{pq}(B)$.)

---

This should be true (with only a few possible exceptions) when $A$ is a field. Indeed every matrix over a field is equivalent to a projection; it follows that $\varphi(M)$ invertible iff $M$ invertible iff $\det(\varphi(M))\neq 0$. Every invertible matrix $M$ can be written as $UD$ where $U\in\mathrm{SL}_p(A)$ and $D=\mathrm{Diag}(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_p)$. Thus when ever $\mathrm{SL}_p(A)=\mathrm{GL}_p(A)'$ holds (and there are [only a few exceptions to this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group#Special_linear_group)) we will get $\det(\varphi(M))=\det(\varphi(\det(M)))$.

---

I initially thought this was true for $A$ a PID since we can use elementary operations on lines to put $M$ into echelon form. But upon inspection I don't know how to deal with the images under $\varphi$ of the matrices used when [improving the pivot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form#Step_II:_Improving_the_pivot) in the Smith Normal Form algorithm.

To wit, we essentially would need to compare, for $\sigma,\tau, \gamma,\delta\in A$ with $\sigma\delta+\tau\gamma = 1_A$,
$$
1=
\det\Bigg(
\underbrace{
\varphi\left(
\det\left(
\begin{matrix}
\sigma&\tau\\
-\gamma&\delta
\end{matrix}
\right)
\right)
}_{=I_n\in M_n(B)}
\Bigg)
\overset?=
\det
\underbrace{
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\varphi(\sigma)&\varphi(\tau)\\
-\varphi(\gamma)&\varphi(\delta)
\end{matrix}
\right)}_{\in M_{2n}(B)}.$$

---

**EDIT.** Equivalently (and justifying the title) the question asks whether when $M_{ij}$, for $1\leq i,j\leq q$ are pairwise commuting matrices in $M_p(B)$ if $$\det(M)=\det\Big(\sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_q}(-1)^\sigma\prod_{1}^qM_{i,\sigma(i)}\Big)$$
where $M$ is the $pq$-square matrix given in block form as $M=(M_{ij})_{i,j}\in M_{pq}(B)$.

---

**Second EDIT.** A Google search revealed a paper proving something almost identical to my question (and identical if we consider the second form from the previous EDIT): **Determinants of Commuting-Block Matrices** by Istvan Kovacs, Daniel S. Silver, and Susan G. Williams. Their proof works over any commutative ring but asks for $A=B$.

Comment: That's not clear: on the right side, $\varphi(\det(M))$ is an element of $B$, so its determinant is itself. What's the point of considering this last determinant?

Comment: @Bernard No, the RHS is an element of $M_p(B)$.

Comment: ??? $\varphi(M)$ might be, but $\det M$ is a scalar, and so is $\varphi(\det M)$. Or is it a problem with the notations?

Comment: $\det(M)$ is an element of $A$, and thus $\varphi(\det(M))$ is an element of $M_n(B)$.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I skimmed over the details of the question…

Comment: No worries. ${}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduce here the proof from the paper **Determinants of Commuting-Block Matrices** by Istvan Kovacs, Daniel S. Silver, and Susan G. Williams.

> **Theorem.** Let $M_{ij}$, $1\leq i,j\leq q$, be pairwise commuting matrices in $M_p(A)$ for some commutative ring $A$ and $B\subset M_p(A)$ the (commutative) subring generated by the $M_{ij}$, and $M=(M_{ij})_{ij}$ the associated block matrix. Then
> $$\det_{M_{pq}(A)}(M) = \det_{M_{p}(A)}(\det_{M_{q}(B)}(M))$$

The proof is by induction on $q$ and uses operations on lines. Viewing $M$ as a matrix in $M_q(B)$ with lines $L_1,\dots,L_q$ we perform the following operations:
$$\begin{cases}
L_2&\leftarrow\quad M_{11}L_2\\
L_3&\leftarrow\quad M_{11}L_3\\
&\ddots\\
L_q&\leftarrow\quad M_{11}L_q
\end{cases}
\qquad\textrm{followed by}\qquad
\begin{cases}
L_2&\leftarrow\quad L_2-M_{21}L_1\\
L_3&\leftarrow\quad L_3-M_{31}L_1\\
&\ddots\\
L_q&\leftarrow\quad L_q-M_{q1}L_1
\end{cases}$$
In matrix terms this is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ -M_{21}&1\\ -M_{31}&&1\\ &&&\ddots \\ -M_{q1}&&&&1
\end{pmatrix}
\times
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\&M_{11}\\&&M_{11}\\ &&&\ddots \\&&&&M_{11}
\end{pmatrix}
\times
M
=
M'
=
\begin{pmatrix}
M_{11}&*&\cdots&*\\
0\\
\vdots&&N\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Next compute both $\displaystyle\det_{M_{pq}(A)}(\bullet)$ and $\displaystyle\det_{M_{p}(A)}(\det_{M_{q}(B)}(\bullet))$ on this product:

- **Computing $\displaystyle\det_{M_{pq}(A)}(\bullet)$:** We find
  $$
  \begin{array}{rcl}
  \displaystyle\det_{M_p(A)}\Big(M_{11}\Big)^{q-1}\cdot\det_{M_{pq}(A)}\Big(M\Big)
  & = &
  \displaystyle\det_{M_{pq}(A)}\Big(M'\Big)\\
  & = &
  \displaystyle\det_{M_p(A)}\Big(M_{11}\Big)\cdot
  \color{orange}{\det_{M_{p(q-1)}(A)}\Big(N\Big)}
  \end{array}$$
- **Computing $\displaystyle\det_{M_{p}(A)}(\det_{M_{q}(B)}(\bullet))$:** first compute in $M_q(B)$:
  $$
  \begin{array}{rcl}
  \displaystyle\Big(M_{11}\Big)^{q-1}\cdot\det_{M_{q}(B)}\Big(M\Big)
  & = &
  \displaystyle\det_{M_{q}(B)}\Big(M'\Big)\\
  & = &
  \displaystyle M_{11}\cdot\det_{M_{q-1}(B)}\Big(N\Big)
  \end{array}$$
  Then apply $\displaystyle\det_{M_p(A)}$:
  $$
  \begin{array}{rcl}
  \displaystyle\Big(\det_{M_p(A)} M_{11}\Big)^{q-1}
  \cdot \det_{M_p(A)}\Big(\det_{M_{q}(B)}\Big(M\Big)\Big)
  & = &
  \displaystyle\det_{M_p(A)}\Big(\det_{M_{q}(B)}\Big(M'\Big)\Big)\\
  & = &
  \displaystyle\det_{M_p(A)}\Big(M_{11}\Big)\cdot
  \color{orange}{\det_{M_p(A)}\Big(\det_{M_{q-1}(B)}\Big(N\Big)\Big)}
  \end{array}$$

We now apply our induction hypothesis: the two orange terms are identical. Therefore
$$\Big(\det_{M_p(A)} M_{11}\Big)^{q-1}
\cdot\bigg[
\det_{M_{pq}(A)}\Big(M\Big)
-
\det_{M_p(A)}\Big(\det_{M_{q}(B)}\Big(M\Big)\Big)
\bigg]
=
0
$$
To deal with $\displaystyle\Big(\det_{M_p(A)} M_{11}\Big)$ which may very well be a zero divisor in $A$ the authors shift to working with matrices with coefficients in $A[T]$ and replace $M_{11}$ with $\widetilde{M_{11}}=T I_n + M_{11}$: then $\displaystyle\Big(\det_{M_p(A[T])} \widetilde{M_{11}}\Big)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $p$ and thus *not a zero divisor in $A[T]$*. Thus, defining $\widetilde{M}$ to have the same coefficients as $M$ except $\widetilde{M}_{11}=\widetilde{M_{11}}$ yields
$$\Big(\det_{M_p(A[T])} \widetilde{M_{11}}\Big)^{q-1}
\cdot\bigg[
\det_{M_{pq}(A[T])}\Big(\widetilde{M}\Big)
-
\det_{M_p(A[T])}\Big(\det_{M_{q}(B[T])}\Big(\widetilde{M}\Big)\Big)
\bigg]
=
0
$$
i.e.
$$\det_{M_{pq}(A[T])}\Big(\widetilde{M}\Big)
=
\det_{M_p(A[T])}\Big(\det_{M_{q}(B[T])}\Big(\widetilde{M}\Big)\Big)$$
and evaluating at $T=0$:
$$\det_{M_{pq}(A)}\Big(M\Big)
=
\det_{M_p(A)}\Big(\det_{M_{q}(B)}\Big(M\Big)\Big).$$